# Traversing Hetrogenous Collection in java

Tags: java, collections

I have collection in which consist of large amount of **Hetrogenous Objects**. e.g.

```
    Employee e1, e2, e3 = new Employee();
    Student s1, s2, s3 = new Student();
    Department d1, d2, d3 = new Department(); 
........etc
```

I need to traverse this collection and all similar objects needs to grouped together and put in another new collection. Means `e1, e2, e3` we can put in one collection.
We can use `InstanceOf`, but that will good if there are only 2-3 types of object.
What will generic solution for this.

Comment: please add what you have tried so far? @Amol

Answer (score 0):

Group them on the objects' classes:

```
Map<Class<?>, Set<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Object obj : collection) {
  map.computeIfAbsent(obj.getClass(), (k) -> new HashSet<Object>())
      .add(obj);
}
```

The resulting map will contain sets of objects with identical classes.

If you've got subclasses (e.g. `class SubStudent extends Student`), these will be in separate classes from their parent classes; if this is not exactly what is desired, you can go back and merge `map.get(SubStudent.class)` with `map.get(Student.class)`, e.g. `map.get(Student.class).addAll(map.remove(SubStudent.class))`.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the instance of the class

```
Map<Class, List<Object>> map = list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o-> o.getClass()));
```